# How to filter records between timestamps from information_schema.warehouse_load_history()

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I want to filter the records between timestamps from **information_schema.warehouse_load_history()** somehow below query is returning the empty result.

Query

```
select date_part(epoch_millisecond, convert_timezone('UTC', END_TIME)), WAREHOUSE_NAME, AVG_RUNNING, AVG_QUEUED_LOAD, AVG_QUEUED_PROVISIONING, AVG_BLOCKED from table(information_schema.warehouse_load_history()) where date_part(epoch_millisecond, convert_timezone('UTC', END_TIME)) >= 1668081337659 and date_part(epoch_millisecond, convert_timezone('UTC', END_TIME)) <= 1668083015000
```

Comment: That looks okay. Are you sure the warehouse was active at that time?

Comment: yes, the warehouse is active. This works when I remove the where clause from the query or just add the where till the first part - 
where date_part(epoch_millisecond, convert_timezone('UTC', END_TIME)) >= 1668081337659

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important point here is, the filters in the WHERE clause will be applied after the warehouse_load_history table function returns a result set. This rule is valid for any information schema table functions (ie query_history).

The function accepts DATE_RANGE_START, DATE_RANGE_END and WAREHOUSE_NAME parameters.

- If an end date is not specified, then CURRENT_DATE is used as the end of the range.
- If a start date is not specified, then the range starts 10 minutes prior to the start of DATE_RANGE_END

So your query only returns the last 10 minutes of data for all warehouses. Your WHERE filter is applied to this returning data.

In short, you should use the filters of the function first (*as I said, it's the same for all information schema functions*), and then you should use the WHERE clause for additional filters.

Comment: I used query like this: 
select date_part(epoch_millisecond, convert_timezone('UTC', END_TIME)), WAREHOUSE_NAME, AVG_RUNNING, AVG_QUEUED_LOAD, AVG_QUEUED_PROVISIONING, AVG_BLOCKED from table(information_schema.warehouse_load_history(date_range_start=>to_timestamp_ntz(1668392049495,3), date_range_end=>to_timestamp_ntz(1668400203568,3)))

This always returns 10 min data no matter what start and end time i am passing. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You might be using that wrong, the dates are a part of the date function itself, no need to add a where clause outside of the table function itself!

For reference: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/warehouse_metering_history.html

Code from ref:
select *
from table(information_schema.warehouse_metering_history('2017-10-23', '2017-10-23', 'testingwh'));